# Unexpected exception caught: com.ptc.pfc.Implementation.pfcExceptions$XToolkitGeneralError while running AsyncInstallTest

Tags: java, jlink

Can any one help to write simple program using jlink java to open creo tool on executing of java program.
what i have done so far is, installed creo-5.0.0.0 and JDK 8 and JLink i was trying to execute some programs, i get above error.
May i know if i have missed anything? i just want basic steps from paths need to set and program to run open creo tool to draw. iam totally new to development only. Any help is appreciated. Thank

```
try
 {
   proe_cmd = "proeCmd -g:no_graphics -i:rpc_input";
   pfcInstallTest.printMsg ("Async install test started.");
   System.loadLibrary ("pfcasyncmt");

   AsyncConnection ac = pfcAsyncConnection.AsyncConnection_Start (proe_cmd, null);
   
   currSession = ac.GetSession ();

   new pfcInstallTest (currSession);
   

   ac.End();

   pfcInstallTest.printMsg ("Async install test completed.");

   System.runFinalization();    
   
   
   

   System.exit (0);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your `try` block wraps several calls which interact with the operating system, with libraries, and with CREO, then there may be several reasons why your connection request fails.

Keep that in mind.

However, when all other possibilities have been addressed, I will share that today we are also discovering that the second argument in the `AsyncConnection_Start` call, when passed the value `null` is a cause of *our* particular connection failure.

When we change that argument to a string path to a user-writable directory, then the attempt to start an asynchronous connection will immediately succeed.

Examples everywhere show that null should be a permissible value but on some systems the argument cannot be null.

Research is underway to understand what causes this.